# Using gridview's DataKeyName in Sql Update Query

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

can someone give me a code example of how to use the selected data key from a gridview as a parameter on a SQL Update query in C#.net

for instance . I am having a gridview bouded with template fields. When i click the select button in the gridview , the selected row information is displayed in textboxes outside the gridview. Now, User can edit that information and click on update button and update the records. To perform this update operation i want DataKeyNames property of the selected row' data to be used. 
Like in Gridview... DataKeyNames="EntryID". So i need this Id again to update the records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

> To perform this update operation i want DataKeyNames property  of the
>   selected row' data to be used.

Actually you save the current ID somewhere on your page the moment you fill your editors, and you use it again to make the Update.

The most easy way is to save it in a read only text editor with title **id:** and on the post back for the Update you have this value-id to make your update.

Other way is to save it on the viewstate.

Also you can read : [Which is the recommended way to fill all controls on a Web Form when user selects a record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358559/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-fill-all-controls-on-a-web-form-when-user-select)