# FormView/GridView master/detail

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework-4, ado.net, master-detail

I'm working on `asp.net framework 4`
I'm looking for a good example of the following case:

I have formview as master data it contains person data:

- person_data_id
- person_name
- age
- ......

The formview contains a datagrid as details data which are family members:

- family_member_id
- person_data_id
- name
- .......

I need to save the detail data to "DataTable"

Page has one `insert` button, inserts both master and detail data to the sql server database.
I'm using linq to get data

I don't know how to create this relation in the page between `formview` and `datagrid` or how to save data to the database at once.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty tutorials about, I suggest the asp.net site, here is the data-access point

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access

a similar answer: [Which is the recommended way to fill all controls on a Web Form when user selects a record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358559/which-is-the-recommended-way-to-fill-all-controls-on-a-web-form-when-user-select/11358903#11358903)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question, for everyone need the solution
Using RadGrid
I bound the details DataTable using NeedDataSource event, fill DataTable from Db and set as datagrid datasource

In InsertCommand: read values from datagrid and insert new Row to DataTable